# Помогите пожалуйста определить тип следующих придаточных предложений

Tags: cинтаксис

1) *Возникало ощущение, будто он и вправду тут, живой как прежде, но только без его мужских прихотей, без его патриархальной требовательности и этой утомительной придирчивости, **чтобы любовь сопровождалась ритуалом неуместных поцелуев и нежных слов**, какие присущи его любви.*

Я сказала бы определительное, но не уверена, может *чтобы* вводить опред. предложение?

2) *Ни тоном, ни стилем, ни духом оно* [письмо] *даже не напоминало о давних годах любви, а смысл был таким разумным и взвешенным, **что запах гардений на нем показался бы просто бестактным**.*

Придаточное степени?

Спасибо!

Comment: uff простите, моя ошибка! хотела сказать "изъяснительное", не "определительное"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***чтобы любовь сопровождалась ритуалом неуместных поцелуев и нежных слов*** - придаточное изъяснительное.

***что запах гардений на нем показался бы просто бестактным*** - придаточное  степени с дополнительном  следственным оттенком.